# cannot get font-awesome to render in heroku production app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, fonts, twitter-bootstrap

I've seen several questions asking something similar, but I can't get this font to render in my production app using a computer that doesn't have the font installed.

http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/

Installed this: https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails

Added this:

```
*= require 'font-awesome'
```

to application.css

The icons ARE working, e.g.:

```
<i class="icon-envelope"></i>
```

correctly renders an envelope icon that is actually one of the font-awesome fonts. However, I can't get the alphabetic font to display in production (I just see Times New Roman). I've tried these instructions to no avail:

http://blog.fieldforceapp.com/moving-to-heroku-bootstrap-font-awesome

I'm concerned there may be a conflict with other css in my stylesheets directory (in app/assets/stylesheets):

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
* compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*

*= require select2
*= require bootstrap-timepicker
*= require 'font-awesome'
*= require_tree .
*= require zpp.css
*/
```

Do I need a separate fonts directory? I'm running rake assets:precompile and see the font .css files moving into my public directory, but still no go.

Would love some help on this b/c I've been scratching my head for too long now. Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever get any resolution to this issue? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: yes! make sure the url referenced in your css contains https and not http if indeed your heroku app is secure (https)

Answer (score 0):

I'd make sure the css file points correctly to the font files.. 
as for the "alphabetic font", font awesome doesnt have a separate font for alpha numeric characters so if your default font is times new roman, that is what you would see..

Comment: thanks Yohn. it's odd because i AM seeing the icons, but all the text font is showing up as times roman

Comment: read my comment again.. 

"font awesome doesnt have a separate font for alpha numeric characters so if your default font is times new roman, that is what you would see" meaning, letters that you see here arent changed when you're using the font awesome font